# Vendor model message sending but in way of Publish/subscribe functionality

Tags: mesh

In this vendor model code i want publish subscribe message functionality because i use node as a low power and friend node and my data is also string ..

issue
in example_ble_mesh_custom_model_cb this call back function not generate event for publish?
it only generate event for send message as it do before.

i tried to make vendor model code to support publish functionality but it cant generate publish event in callback function.

i want that this pub/subscribe functionality work in this model.